# Get time from Timestamp stored as varchar

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, phpmyadmin

I have timestamps in `varchar(20)` like `'01-11-2012 11:36:53.122'`

If I get only date by

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("01-11-2012 11:36:53.122", '%d-%m-%Y')
```

it gives this output: `"2012-11-01"`.

But by this

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("01-11-2012 11:36:53.122", '%H:%i:%s')
```

it gives the output `"null"` instead of `11:36:53`.

What is query to get only the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

give this a try

```
DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(`column`, '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s'), '%H:%i:%s')
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4e800/4)

Other sources,

- [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT date_format(STR_TO_DATE("01-11-2012 11:36:53.122", '%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%s.%f'), '%H:%i:%s')
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8/5226)

Answer (score -1):

Change your field format to `datetime`.

That's the only proper way to store datetime values.

Comment: what if the user is not allowed to alter the table or there are already front-end applications accessing the table and the table contains thousand of record already?